# Yii2 debug panels are only showing when there's an error

Tags: yii, yii2

I'm using Yii2's [debug profiler](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-debug/blob/master/docs/guide/README.md) and everything seems to be set up correctly (I'm in debug mode, my ip is allowed, etc) but the debug bar is only showing when there's a Yii exception, for example, if I try to access `Yii::$app->paramssssss['test']` which will show the debug page and the debug bar. On any other page, it's not shown.

Did something similar ever happened to anyone? [This guy had the same issue](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-debug/issues/156) but it was a Vagrant issue, and I'm not using Vagrant.

Here are parts of my config:

```
...
'bootstrap' => ['debug'],
...
if (YII_ENV_DEV) {
    // configuration adjustments for 'dev' environment
    $config['bootstrap'][] = 'debug';
    $config['modules']['debug'] = [
        'class' => 'yii\debug\Module',
        'panels' => [
            'db' => [
                'class' => 'yii\debug\panels\DbPanel',
                'defaultOrder' => [
                    'seq' => SORT_ASC
                ],
                'defaultFilter' => [
                    'type' => 'SELECT'
                ]
            ],
            'user' => [
                'class'=>'yii\debug\panels\UserPanel',
                'ruleUserSwitch' => [
                    'allow' => true,
                    'roles' => ['manager'],
                ]
            ],
        ],
        // uncomment the following to add your IP if you are not connecting from localhost.
        'allowedIPs' => ['127.0.0.1', '::1', '*'],
    ];
}
...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably you're not triggering required events in your layout. Make sure that you have something like this at the end of your layout file:

```
<?php $this->endBody() ?>
</body>
</html>
<?php $this->endPage() ?>
```

You should also read [this guide article](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/structure-views#creating-layouts) and make sure that you have all required triggers in your layout - omitting them can result in many hard to debug bugs.

Comment: Very useful info thanks! I already feel like the old messed up code is getting better :) Unfortunately this doesn't make the debug panel show..

Comment: Ok.. I have no idea what happened but after making the suggested changes this morning, the panels didn't show then just recently they started showing mysteriously. I tried looking at my changes to see what did the trick but there's nothing related so I guess your answer was the solution, thanks again!

Comment: THIS! Two hours of debugging and I arrived at the same answer.